# Why SwiftUI Image add an extra padding to enclosing VStack?

Tags: swiftui, padding

I'm struggling with a very simple problem. If I put a Text into a VStack, there is no padding on the top. If I now put an Image, I have a padding. See the following screenshot:

[image]

The corresponding code is:

```swift
struct NewView: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Text("Some title")
                .font(.headline)

            VStack {
                Text("Some text")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color(white: 0.90))
            .cornerRadius(10)


            Divider()
                .padding(.vertical)

            Text("Some title")
                .font(.headline)

            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "1.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .fixedSize()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.yellow)

            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color(white: 0.90))
            .cornerRadius(10)

        }
    }
}
```

The answer is probably very simple. What did I miss?
Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are different default paddings between different UI elements, if you want explicit, use `spacing` as below

`VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {`

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised that the content of the VStack modifies it's default padding. I would have expected an identical padding whatever the content of the VStack. Thanks again!

Comment: @VincentGarcia, it is documented feature: "spacing: the distance between adjacent children, or nil if the stack should choose a *default distance for each pair of children*".

Comment: In both examples, the two children of a given pair are a Text and a VStack. And yet the distance is different depending on the content of the VStack.

Comment: It would be useful to see the complete solution. In which VStack do we put "spacing: 0"?